# Can we stabilize particles other than the neutron in a lab setting?

Tags: particle-physics

There are so many elementary and composite particles out there, but only a few that are stable and isolatible - namely protons, electrons, photons and neutrinos (oscillating in the three flavors). These compromise most of the particles we interact with day-to-day, with the exception of the neutron, which has a proper decay time of ~15 minutes in the rest frame. However, we know that in bound states like most atoms and neutron stars, that the neutron is stabilized against decay because of the significant binding energy in an atomic nucleus.

Its my understand that in neutron stars people have theorized all sorts of exotic states of matter where 'uncommon' quickly decaying particles are now stable. But what is the extent that particles other than the neutron can be stabilized in the lab? Is it possible, for example, to find bound states of other baryons or of muons that significantly increase the lifetime of the particles? I understand its unlikely that anything as stable as an atomic nucleus is possible in 'reasonable conditions' (or else we would have already seen it in nature) but how much can we extend the proper lifetime of 'uncommon' matter outside of a neutron star?